# Magento model can't delete row

Tags: magento, model, magento-1.9.1

I m trying to delete my db table row using below code from observer. but can't delete it gives error in system log

```
 Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back

$customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost();
             //$groupCodeArray = $customFieldValue['product']['customer_group_ids'];

             $DataCollectionDel = Mage::getModel('customerspecificproduct/customerspecificproduct')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(
                'product_ids',
                array(
                    'eq'=>$product->getId()
                )
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'group_id',
                array(
                    'notnull'=>true,
                )
            );


            if($DataCollectionDel){
             foreach($DataCollectionDel as $data){
                    $deleteRow = Mage::getModel('customerspecificproduct/customerspecificproduct')->load($data->getId())->delete();

                }
             }exit;
```

Comment: Modify your code using try catch. Print or log exception in catch block. Because there may be a chance of exception

Comment: May be the row that you are trying to delete is the foreign key in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself

```
$DataCollectionDel = Mage::getModel('customerspecificproduct/customerspecificproduct')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(
                'product_ids',
                array(
                    'eq'=>$product->getId()
                )
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'group_id',
                array(
                    'notnull'=>true,
                )
            );



             try{
                if($DataCollectionDel){
             foreach($DataCollectionDel as $data){
                    $data->delete();
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for it :3 without **getCollection()**. 
Model

```
 public function deleteByCondition($itemId,$vendor)
    {
        return $this->getResource()->deleteByCondition($itemId,$vendor);
    }
```

Resource Model

```
  public function deleteByCondition($itemId,$vendor)
    {
        $table = $this->getMainTable();
        $where = array();
        $where[] =  $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('item_id = ?',$itemId);
        $where[] =  $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto("vendor = ? ", $vendor);
        $result = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($table,$where);
        return $result;
    }
```